# PostMessage not clicking buttons

Tags: c++, winapi

I've played with PostMessage just clicking different tabs which seemed to work. But I'm trying to automate some button clicks and when running this function it highlights the button as if I was hovering over it but doesn't click.
I thought somehow the button changing of colour made the boolean false so I added the exception of the buttons colour whilst it's hovered. Made no difference, and I do not wish to use SetCursorPos & simulate a mouseclick using SendInput. I wish to understand the problem/issue I'm having as to why it's not clicking.

```
void click(const std::vector<uint_16>& x, const uint_16& y)
{
    for(uint_8 i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if(content::MyClass().firstMatch(GetPixel(hdc, x[i], y)))
        {
            PostMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, MAKELPARAM(x[i], y));
            return;
        }
    }
    if(content::MyClass().secondMatch(GetPixel(hdc, x[4], y)))
    {
        PostMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, MAKELPARAM(x[4], y));
    }
}
```

Comment: Testing with the buttons in an editor's exit dialog, it appears that nothing happens until I release the mouse key. You only tell the `hwnd` (presumably the button) that the mouse key has been pressed. When it's never release nothing happens.

Comment: 'I do not wish to use SetCursorPos & simulate a mouseclick using SendInput.' - Why not? This is the recommended way of simulating mouse clicks.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Cheers mate! I kind of feel like an idiot now lol.

Comment: @beerboy I am using many threads to do this simultaneously and having SetCursorPos is not viable for this.

Comment: Why did you reject UIAutomation?

Comment: You are right about one thing: It **seemed** to have worked. In reality, it didn't. Faking input by posting messages may convince the recipient, but it will fail to update the input system. For more details on an identical problem, see [Simulating input via WM_CHAR messages may fake out the recipient but it won't fake out the input system](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/07/29/10190521.aspx). The solution is to either use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx), or post a `BM_CLICK` message instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution you are using is unreliable because you are short-circuiting the input system on the window and not specifically targeting which button you are trying to press.

As for the reason your code is not currently working, you only send a `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` message to the window. Since most buttons work off a combination of `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_LBUTTONUP` your program isn't causing the buttons click method to activate.

Adding `PostMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, MAKELPARAM(x[i], y));` after the mouse down will cause the button click to register.

In future as a more reliable solution that will specifically target a button on the window and click it you may want to look at the [`BM_CLICK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775985.aspx) PostMessage argument. Using this instead of trying to emulate a mouse click is more correct because windows will trigger events that may otherwise be forgotten when using the mouse down and mouse up post commands.

An example:

```
int retVal = 0;
HANDLE hwndDialog;
HANDLE hwndButton;

/* First, see if the dialog box (titled "Inactivity Warning" ) is currently open. */
hwndDialog = FindWindow( 0, "Inactivity Warning" );
if ( hwndDialog == 0 ) return;

/* Now get a handle to the "Resume" button in the dialog. */
hwndButton = FindWindowEx( hwndDialog, 0, 0, "Resume" );

/* After making sure that the dialog box is the active window, click "Resume". */
retval = SetActiveWindow( hwndDialog );

/* converted from SendMessage. */
retval = PostMessage( hwndButton, BM_CLICK, 0, 0 );
```

Source [found Here](http://www.jasinskionline.com/windowsapi/ref/b/bm_click.html), Converted from VB by me.

For some further reading on the input system [Here is a good article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645601.aspx).
A [Blog Post by Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/30/423202.aspx) goes into a bit of detail about these commands and their caveats as well.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely take a look into `BN_CLICKED`

Comment: `BN_CLICKED` is a notification message that the button sends to its parent window to notify it that the button has been clicked. To actual click the button, send [`BM_CLiCK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775985.aspx) to the button itself. That will generate `WM_LBUTTONDOWN/UP` and `BN_CLICKED` messages.

Comment: Suggesting to fake input by posting input messages is not a solution. Proposing to add a `Sleep` between down and up messages makes matters worse: It doesn't change anything, and implies, that it is a solution. Again, it isn't. Removing everything but the last paragraph would turn this post into a valid answer.

Comment: @IInspectable Looking at the answer, you are right. It's a very sub optimal solution for a problem that is easily solved by `BM_CLICK`. I've updated the answer to show this.

Comment: While improved, the answer still doesn't go into specifics, what's unreliable about faking mouse input through posted `WM_LBUTTONxyz` messages. The pixel location is the least of your worries. Bypassing the input system, however, is a serious offence: Those fake mouse messages won't reset the screensaver timeout, for example. `GetQueueStatus` will only see real input, and doesn't account for the posted messages. Likewise, `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` won't return when you filter on `QS_MOUSE`. Mouse hooks won't get called either. In short: You broke the system in the worst imaginable way.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm quite curious now, although I understand what you're saying I have no knowledge of that depth in the input system. I'll rove MSDN for information but do you know of a solid place to read up about such things? If so I'll add it to the answer for anyone who wants further reading.

Comment: The closest you will find on MSDN is [About Mouse Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645601.aspx). It doesn't explicitly spell out the obvious, though: Mouse messages are the **result** of input processing. Posting the same messages to a message queue, doesn't go back in time and magically generates appropriate (hardware) input events. Raymond Chen frequently writes about, what's obvious to him. [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/30/423202.aspx) addresses a similar issue.